# R Poisson simulation function

Tags: r, function, simulation, poisson, exp

I would like to write a function that calculates the number of arrivals until time t in n
different trials. I know that the arguments should include the exponential parameter lambda, the time t, and the number of counts n to be sampled. It should return a vector with n elements, corresponding to the counts.

Progress: I have created a function that counts the number of events until time t,and I will need to use the rexp() function.

But how do I do this poisson function?

Answer (score 2):

The following simulates a Poisson process. The function `Nt` takes two arguments, the exponential rate and the time limit.

```
Nt <- function(lambda = 1, t){
  S <- 0                 # Total time, sum of X's 
  n <- 0L                # Number of events
  repeat{
    X <- rexp(1, lambda)  # New time between events
    if(S + X > t) break   # Above the limit time t?
    S <- S + X            # No, update total time S
    n <- n + 1L           # and the nr. of events counter
  }
  n
}

set.seed(2021)

Rate <- 2
Time <- 10
N <- replicate(1e4, Nt(lambda = Rate, t = Time))
tbl <- table(N)
plot(tbl/sum(tbl), lwd = 10, col = "grey")
lines(0:40, dpois(0:40, lambda = Time*Rate), type = "h", col = "red")
```

[image]